# R- outer with matrix

Tags: arrays, r, closures

Let's suppose I want to minimize a function:

```
x<-seq(-4.5,4.5,by=.2)
y<-seq(-4.5,4.5,by=.2)
f <- function(x1,x2){(x1^2 + x2)^2 }
z <- outer(x,y,f)
```

Where z is a matrix of dimension 46 x 46:

```
  > class(z)
[1] "matrix"
> dim(z)
[1] 46 46
```

So I make a graph of the result with:

```
persp(x,y,z,phi=-45,theta=45,col="yellow",shade=.65 ,ticktype="detailed")
```

If I write the previous, it works, but since I want to minimize the function using optim, if I use that I get:

```
optim(c(-4,-4), f, df)$par

> Error in fn(par, ...) : argument "x2" is missing, with no default
```

So I need to use an array in order to use optim after all. So if I write:

```
f <- function(x) (x[1]^2 + x[2])^2 
x <- seq(-4.5,4.5,by=.2)
y <- seq(-4.5,4.5,by=.2)
s<-data.frame(cbind(x,y))
```

I can use optim:

```
optim(c(-4,-4), f, df)$par
```

But outer gives an error:

```
z <- outer(s,f)
```

> Error in as.vector(x, mode) :    cannot coerce type 'closure' to
>   vector of type 'any'

I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: `?outer` expects "FUN" to have at least two arguments. Also, you are calling `outer` with your "f" in its "Y" argument and this gives the error. What exactly do you want to avoid? Can't you, simply, use something like `outer(s$x, s$y, function(x, y) (x^2 + y) ^ 2)`?

Comment: No, I need to keep the function as function(x) (x[1]^2+x[2])^2

Comment: Perhaps you need `expand.grid` + `apply`? I.e. get all the combinations of your arguments and apply "f" on them. E.g.: `args = expand.grid(data.frame(dim1 = paste0("A", 1:2), dim2 = paste0("B", 1:2), dim3 = paste0("C", 1:2), dim4 = paste0("D", 1:2)))` and, then, `apply(args, 1, function(x) paste(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], sep = "-"))`

Comment: I don't get why you are doing the expand grid. can you continue with the example data? (I edited the post)

Comment: FYI, it makes more sense to have `s` as a list of vectors, in case you want to evaluate the function on a non-square grid. (I edited this into the answer.) And, for future reference, the question might be clearer if the two versions of `f` had different names above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the goal here is to not have to write the function two different ways, right?

```
f0 <- function(x1,x2) ( x1^2   + x2   )^2
f  <- function(x)     ( x[1]^2 + x[2] )^2
```

Similarly, maybe you just want to use just `s<-data.frame(cbind(x,y))` (without `x` and `y`).

Here's what I would consider doing:

```
outer(s[[1]],s[[2]],Vectorize(function(xi,yi) f(c(xi,yi))))
```

This way you only have to write the function once, in the way amenable to using `optim` (with a single argument).

---

**Note:** If you want the grids `x` and `y` to have a different number of points, you should store `s <- list(x,y)` instead. The code will work the same.